# NSURLConnection times out after reopening app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

In my app I use a NSURLConnection to upload some content.
Everything works fine except when I reopen the app after like one hour.

The NSURLConnection will timeout every time at the first try. After that the app works fine.

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
[connection start];
```

Using [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request...] also leads to a timeout.

On another thread on the Apple developer forum somebody suggested to run a packet trace, which I did. The request does not seem to be sent.

I'm a bit out of ideas, do you have one ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you `init` an `NSURLConnection` the way you do, you do not need to call `-start`. Try getting rid of that line and seeing if that helps anything.

Comment: will try that, in an hour approximately :)

Comment: Wow, that might be it...I'll try again a few times today to confirm. Thanks mbm !

Comment: Unfortunately I've reproduced my bug...